# Django Boolean Field returning "---------" as value

Tags: django, forms, radio-button, modelform

I'm creating a form based on a model, where I have a boolean field as this:

```
project_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=JOB_TYPES)
```

Choices are:

```
  JOB_TYPES = (
    ('fulltime', _('Fulltid')),
    ('project', _('Prosjektbasert')),
  )
```

To display the input type as radio buttons rather than , I'm doing this:

```
    class AddJob(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Jobs
    widgets = {
        'project_type': RadioSelect(),
    }
```

In the HTML, the form output looks like this:

```
 <label for="id_for_project_type_0">Project type</label> 
 <ul>
 <li><label for="id_for_project_type_0"><input checked="checked" type="radio"      id="id_for_project_type_0" value="" name="project_type" /> ---------</label></li>
 <li><label for="id_for_project_type_1"><input type="radio" id="id_for_project_type_1" value="fulltime" name="project_type" /> Fulltid</label></li>
 <li><label for="id_for_project_type_2"><input type="radio" id="id_for_project_type_2" value="project" name="project_type" /> Prosjektbasert</label></li>
 </ul>
```

Why am I getting a value 0? I've only specified two values in the model. And how do I get rid of it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a [default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#default) for `project_type`:

```
project_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=JOB_TYPES,
                                default=JOB_TYPES[0][0])
```